# Signalr1.0.0.0 + unity + entity framework broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, entity-framework-5, signalr

Today I upgraded to Signalr 1.0.0 from 1.0.0alpha2 and I noticed I had to change my `Application_Start`.

Before:

```
UnityContainer = Bootstrapper.Initialize();
var unityDependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(unityDependencyResolver);

var signalRUnityDependencyResolver = new SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);

RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(signalRUnityDependencyResolver);

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRUnityDependencyResolver;

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Now:

```
UnityContainer = Bootstrapper.Initialize();
var unityDependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(unityDependencyResolver);

var signalRUnityDependencyResolver = new SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);
//RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(signalRUnityDependencyResolver);
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRUnityDependencyResolver;

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

I know the docs state that `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` should come first but this will just make everything hang on that line. This is the only way I found that actually loaded.

But when I try to make a database call I don't get an exception or anything but the website will freeze. When I hit pause in the debugger it is frozen on the first EF5 query it comes across. But there is no exception, all properties are indicated as:

`Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.`

When I remove `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` everything works again (except for  Signalr).

Sometimes it doesn't even get that far and then it hangs on `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`.

Every update of Signalr this changes again and it's driving me crazy now.

What should be the correct order of calling to get Unity+Signalr working?

**Edit:** 
After some fiddeling around it seems to work when I disable the following lines:

```
var signalRUnityDependencyResolver = new SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(UnityContainer);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRUnityDependencyResolver;
```